# ASP.Net Core 3 with Autofac ignores iis settings; log displays "Now listening on: http://localhost:5000"

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, autofac, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm running an Asp.net core 3.0 web API using Autofac. Its entry-point looks like this:

```
using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Myapp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            IHostBuilder builder = CreateHostBuilder(currentDirectory, args);
            using IHost host = builder.Build();
            host.Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string currentDirectory, string[] args)
        {
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                       .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
                       .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                       {
                         webBuilder
                           .UseContentRoot(currentDirectory)
                           .UseIISIntegration()
                           .UseStartup<Startup>();
                       });
        }
    }
}
```

Using the following appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Authentication": {
    "AllowAnonymous": false
  },
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:5000"
      },
      "HttpsInlineCertFile": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5001",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "a.pfx",
          "Password": "a"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and launching it as a console application, like this:

```
dotnet myapp.dll
```

it runs correctly.

Launching it in debug mode from Visual Studio under IIS Express, it also runs correctly (on https port 44393).

I then configured it under IIS. I set the bindings to HTTP port 95 and HTTPS port 96 and enabled stdout log in the web.config file.
When attempting to access the application from a browser, though, the call fails and the stdout log file displays:

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.EphemeralXmlRepository[50]
      Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[59]
      Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {c74e2418-52e2-492d-b49e-b28c053e4cc3} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
2019-12-02 14:14:20,820 INFO  (1) Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime - Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info2019-12-02 14:14:20,827 INFO  (1) Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime - Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

This (the line saying that it is listening to port 5000, in particular) looks like the same output displayed under default configuration (i.e.: when no configuration is applied). So, it seems to me that all settings provided to IIS are ignored or don't get applied.

Where is the mistake? How can the problem be solved?

Comment: You mention in the question title specifically "with Autofac" and tag `autofac` here - have you done something to narrow down that this is Autofac related? It sounds a bit like a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring).

Comment: The point is that "something" doesn't work, but I don't know exactly what. It may be an error due to the use of Autofac, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Hi Starnuto, it is [your task](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as poster to help us as much as you can, by limiting down the problem to the least amount of code that allows anyone to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Program.cs, Did you enable IISIntegration?

```
      webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel()
          .UseIISIntegration() <<-----
          .UseSetting("detailedErrors", "true")
          .CaptureStartupErrors(true)
          .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Comment: Yes, it's in method CreateHostBuilder